# WCF Authentication WITHOUT SSL

Tags: wcf, security, rest, ssl

Is there a way to setup authentication (ala "Basic Authentication") without actually setting up an SSL Certificate?  I'd also like to do this in REST or regular SOAP WCF Services, preferably in REST, but would like to be able to mix the services.  In other words, "I want to be able to send a regular old username and password just like in Basic Authentication but without the SSL."  Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use TransportCredentialOnly security mode. This post explains how to do it:

http://developers.de/blogs/damir_dobric/archive/2006/07/31/890.aspx.

Don't forget that you also have to enable basic authentication in IIS.

Comment: I guess this is only possible in WCF4, not WCF3-3.5?

Comment: I used it with WCF3.5. Took some luck to get it working, though, if I remember correctly.

Comment: Just a note about TransportCredentialOnly: The TransportCredentialOnly security mode option passes the user credentials without encrypting or signing the messages. Use this mode with caution as it will not protect the credentials being transmitted and they will have to be protected by some other means, such as Internet Protocol Security (IPSec). [From http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff648505.aspx]

Comment: @erikkallen I've followed this and enabled basic authentication within IIS express but I'm still getting a `SOAP header is missing` exception. Any ideas please?

Comment: Is this the same as None security mode in WCF4?