# Implement Authentication in a WCF service (non ssl)

Tags: c#, wcf, ssl, sap

I have developed a .NET WCF service which uses basicHttp binding. This service is going to be hosted in IIS in an intranet and consumed by a non-Windows SAP PO client.

This service doesn't expose any sensitive information So I do not want to invest time on signing or encrypting messages. However, I also do not want the service to be accessed by anyone who knows the URL. so some form of authentication is required.

Can anyone please advise what would be the simplest way to authenticate my service?

**UPDATE :**

Thanks Keyur PATEL. I managed to host the service in IIS as per the link provided with security mode being set to "TransportCredentialOnly"

I enabled Basic Authentication in IIS

My windows client is able to subscribe the service however It receives below error when an operation is executed.

"The HTTP request is unauthorized with client authentication scheme 'Basic'. The authentication header received from the server was 'Basic realm="MY SERVER NAME"'.

**Server Config**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="CustomAuthentication">
          <security mode="TransportCredentialOnly">
            <transport clientCredentialType="Basic" proxyCredentialType="Basic"/>
          </security>
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="SecurityBehavior">
          <serviceCredentials>
            <userNameAuthentication userNamePasswordValidationMode="Custom" customUserNamePasswordValidatorType="SimpleService.UserNamePasswordAuthentification, App_Code/UserNameValidator"/>
          </serviceCredentials>
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <services>
      <service behaviorConfiguration="SecurityBehavior" name="SimpleService.SimpleService">
        <endpoint address="SimpleService" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="CustomAuthentication" contract="SimpleService.ISimpleService"/>
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="http://localhost:8080"/>
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
      </service>
    </services>
  </system.serviceModel>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true"/>
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

**Client Config**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <system.serviceModel>
        <bindings>
            <basicHttpBinding>
                <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_ISimpleService">
                    <security mode="TransportCredentialOnly">
                        <transport clientCredentialType="Basic" />
                    </security>
                </binding>
            </basicHttpBinding>
        </bindings>
        <client>
            <endpoint address="http://MYSERVERNAME:PORT/SimpleService.svc/SimpleService"
                binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_ISimpleService"
                contract="SimpleServiceDEV.ISimpleService" name="BasicHttpBinding_ISimpleService" />
        </client>
    </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Are you working with any database in the back end?

Comment: No. Service performs some basic calculations in its business logic and returns the result as a string.

Comment: This link could help: [WCF Authentication WITHOUT SSL](https://stackoverflow.com/a/393735/6741868).